# Splitting a string list list

Tags: f#

I'm quite (very) new to F# and I'm scratching my head over a little problem. I have a `string list list` that I'm trying to manipulate and transform. This is probably trivial.

The following data is being read in from a CSV file:

```
1,ABC,3
1,DEF,3
1,XYZ,1
2,ABC,2
2,XYZ,1
3,DEF,2
3,XYZ,2
```

Which right or wrong, I'm reading into a `string list list`. This data represents a non-normalized set of data, where the field at index `0` on each record is an Identifier field. At the moment I'm just trying to split the outer-list up so that I end up with a `string list list list` representing the following:

```
1,ABC,3        2,ABC,2        3,DEF,2
1,DEF,3        2,XYZ,1        3,XYZ,2
1,XYZ,1
```

The results above will then be pushed into my Typed model and fed into the rest of the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code:

```
csvRecords
|> Seq.groupBy (fun record -> (record.Item 0))
|> List.ofSeq
|> List.map(toTypedModel)
```

`record.Item 0` isn't a good way to get the first element of a list. You should either use `List.head` or pattern matching for that purpose.

Your example would look like:

```
csvRecords
|> Seq.groupBy List.head
|> Seq.map toTypedModel
|> List.ofSeq
```

I also changed the order to use `toTypedModel` with sequence, it helps to avoid allocating an unnecessary list.

Comment: That makes sense, I've gone with that - the `List.head` is spot on!

Answer (score 1):

Use `Seq.groupby` -

```
input
|> Seq.groupBy (fun (a,b,c) -> a)
|> Seq.toList
```

Comment: Thanks John - I had used `Seq.groupBy` already - but the List of 2 tuples returned through me off completely. I've since understood more about how to deal with tuples so going back to your answer has done the trick! 

Now in the function that the result of this function is mapped to, I just break down the tuple into it's parts.

I knew it would be trivial.

Comment: @JohnPalmer: `List.toSeq` is superfluous and `Seq.GroupBy/Seq.Groupby` are in wrong cases.

Comment: @pad - thats what happens when I dont test with the compiler